# How to retrieve insights API for ad in day-granularity on Facebook?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to retrieve the insights data in day-granularity from Facebook API.
This is the request I use:

`1234548/insights?fields=ad_id,impressions,account_id,created_time,adset_id,campaign_id,clicks,conversions&time_range={'since':'2023-01-01','until':'2023-05-20'}`

The response:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "ad_id": "xxxxxxxx",
      "impressions": "54367",
      "account_id": "xxxxxxxx",
      "created_time": "2023-05-17",
      "adset_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "campaign_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "clicks": "853",
      "date_start": "2023-01-01",
      "date_stop": "2023-05-20"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

I picked an ad that was created on the 17.5, and expected to receive JSON with the data for a 1-day  granularity, but received the metrics summarized as you can see with the clicks.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your API request by adding the `time_increment` (`enum{monthly, all_days} or integer`) parameter with a value of `1` for daily. Try;

```
1234548/insights?fields=ad_id,impressions,account_id,created_time,adset_id,campaign_id,clicks,conversions&time_range={'since':'2023-01-01','until':'2023-05-20'}&time_increment=1
```

You should receive daily granularity data in the response. Screenshot of [time_increment on Meta Dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN8eQ.png) and website [ref](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v16.0) for some fun reading.